# How to handle 401 (Authentication Error) in axios and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, token, axios, http-status-code-401

I have one file request.js which contains wrapper for axios ajax request. I am calling request function from multiple react components and when one of the request fails I want to refresh the token and retry all the failed requests again. I can use intercepters, but I don't know how to implement it. Please help.

request.js

```
 var client = axios.create({
   baseURL: 'http://192.168.1.3:3000',
     headers: {
     appID: 8,
     version: "1.1.0",
     empID: localStorage.getItem('empID'),
     token: localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
    }
 });

 const request = function(options) {
     const onSuccess = function(response) {
         console.debug('Request Successful!', response);
         return response.data;
     } 
     const onError = function(error) {
         console.error('Request Failed:', error.config);
         if (error.response) {
             console.error('Status:',  error.response.status);
             console.error('Data:',    error.response.data);
             console.error('Headers:', error.response.headers);
         } else {
             console.error('Error Message:', error.message);
         }

         return Promise.reject(error.response || error.message);
     }

     return client(options)
         .then(onSuccess)
         .catch(onError);
         options
 }

 export default request;
```

Comment: I catch 401 using this method: ```axios.post('/endpoint').then(...).catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error.response.status) //401
       console.log(error.response.data.error) // Please Authenticate
})```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I got it working with the following code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import config from '../../configuration.json';
import qs from 'qs';

const baseURL = config['baseUrl_local'];
let authTokenRequest;

/**
  * @description axios instance for ajax requests
*/ 

var client = axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL,
    headers: {
        appID: 8,
        version: "1.1.0",
        empID: localStorage.getItem('empID'),
        token: localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
    }
});

/**
 * @description this method calls a requestNewToken method to issue a 
 new token to the client
*/ 

 function getAuthToken() {
   if (!authTokenRequest) {
     authTokenRequest = requestNewToken();
     authTokenRequest.then(resetAuthTokenRequest, resetAuthTokenRequest);
   }

   return authTokenRequest;
 }

/**
  * @description this method requests the server to issue a new token, 
  the server response is updated in local storage accessToken
*/ 

function requestNewToken() {
  var newToken = request({
  method: "post",
  url: '/sign-in',
  data:  qs.stringify({
         "userName":localStorage.getItem('userName'),
         "password":localStorage.getItem('password')
         })  
  }).then((res)=>{
  if(res.status == "success"){
    localStorage.setItem('accessToken',res.data.accessToken);
    //if featureArray is present in response object, update the 
    featureArray in local storage
    if(res.data.features){
      localStorage.setItem(
      'featureArray',
     JSON.stringify(res.data.features));
    }
    client = axios.create({
     baseURL: baseURL,
     headers: {
          appID: 8,
          version: "1.1.0",
          empID: localStorage.getItem('empID'),
          token: localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
      }
   });
 } else {
  window.location = "/logout";
 }
});

 return newToken;
}

function resetAuthTokenRequest() {
  authTokenRequest = null;
 }

/**
  * @description if any of the API gets 401 status code, this method 
   calls getAuthToken method to renew accessToken
  * updates the error configuration and retries all failed requests 
  again
*/ 

client.interceptors.response.use(undefined, err => {
  const error = err.response;
  // if error is 401 
  if (error.status===401 && error.config && 
  !error.config.__isRetryRequest) {
  // request for a new token
  return getAuthToken().then(response => {
   // update the error config with new token
   error.config.__isRetryRequest = true;
   error.config.headers.token= localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
   return client(error.config);
  });
 } 
});

/**
 * @description wrapper for making ajax requests
 * @param {object} object with method,url,data etc.
*/ 

const request = function(options) {
  const onSuccess = function(response) {
    return response.data;
  }
 const onError = function(error) {
  //console.error('Request Failed:', error.config);
   if (error.response) {
  //console.error('Status:',  error.response.status);
  //console.error('Data:',    error.response.data);
  //console.error('Headers:', error.response.headers);
  } else {
  console.error('Error Message:', error.message);
  }
 return Promise.reject(error.response || error.message);
 }

return client(options)
        .then(onSuccess)
        .catch(onError);
        options
}

export default request;
```

[EDIT] Its 2019, Here is yet another implementation for the same. The above solution is great but does not work well with multiple failed request, in turn it calls getToken with the updated token as well.

```
 import axios from "axios";

 /* @internal */
 import config from "../config";
 import TokenService from "./token_service"; // Could You please provide code from this file too?

class Request {
    constructor() {
        this.baseURL = config.baseUrl;
        this.isRefreshing = false;
        this.failedRequests = [];
        this.tokenService = new TokenService();
        this.client = axios.create({
            baseURL: config.apiServerBaseUrl,
            headers: {
               clientSecret: this.clientSecret,
            },
        });
        this.beforeRequest = this.beforeRequest.bind(this);
        this.onRequestFailure = this.onRequestFailure.bind(this);
        this.processQueue = this.processQueue.bind(this);
        this.client.interceptors.request.use(this.beforeRequest);
        this.client.interceptors.response.use(this.onRequestSuccess, 
this.onRequestFailure);
}

beforeRequest(request) {
    const token = TokenService.getAccessToken();
    request.headers.Authorization = `Token ${token}`;
    return request;
}

static onRequestSuccess(response) {
    return response.data;
}

async onRequestFailure(err) {
    const { response } = err;
    if (response.status === 401 && err && err.config && !err.config.__isRetryRequest) {
        if (this.isRefreshing) {
            try {
                const token = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    this.failedRequests.push({ resolve, reject });
                });
                err.config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
                return this.client(err.config);
            }
            catch (e) {
                return e;
            }
        }
        this.isRefreshing = true;
        err.config.__isRetryRequest = true;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.tokenService.refreshAccessToken().then((token) => {
                this.tokenService.setAccessToken(token);
                err.config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
                this.isRefreshing = false;
                this.processQueue(null, token);
                resolve(this.client(err.config));
            }).catch((e) => {
                this.processQueue(e, null);
                reject(err.response);
            });
        });
    }
    throw response;
}

processQueue(error, token = null) {
    this.failedRequests.forEach((prom) => {
        if (error) {
            prom.reject(error);
        } else {
            prom.resolve(token);
        }
       });
        this.failedRequests = [];
    }

}

const request = new Request();

export default request.client;
```

Answer (score 139):

If you want to use interceptors to handle 401 error here is code snippet.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
   return response;
}, error => {
  if (error.response.status === 401) {
   //place your reentry code
  }
  return error;
});
```

Comment: Did this change? response is always undefined for 401, I get a `Network Error` in Axios instead...

Comment: @estani Did you figure it out? Same for me, due to 403 i'm getting `Network Error` and Axios error contains no `response` nor `status`.

Comment: @LittleTiger from server side if you don't get any response other than status, then this approach won't work. If you want to use the above approach then please send response with status. ie. res.status(401).send("message") or res.status(401).json({})

Comment: @estani Did you find a solution?

Comment: @TarasKryvko yes, I've added an answer here, though the problem might be a different one.

Comment: @Pram Is there an easy way to resend the request after silently handling reauthentication?

Comment: I am change *return error* to *return Promise.reject(error);*

Comment: It's wrong. `throw error`

Answer (score 21):

This works:

```js
// Add a 401 response interceptor
window.axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    return response;
}, function (error) {
    if (401 === error.response.status) {
        // handle error: inform user, go to login, etc
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
});
```

Extracted from:
https://gist.github.com/yajra/5f5551649b20c8f668aec48549ef5c1f

I had this extra issue:

#### "Network Error" without any response

tl;dr - It was a problem with CORS and how it was setup, so axios never got the information back from the browser. You have to sort it out from the server side.

**Description**

if you have a similar problem, you'll see it in the browser console. The browser will prevent you from accessing a different url over ajax.

In my particular case (node.js - express) was the order of the filter, the CORS filter (dev environment) was added after the handler for this particular request, so the server wasn't sending the proper CORS headers at the time and thus the browser wasn't even allowing the request to take place (there was no call to the server whatsoever, thus no error object got returned).

Comment: Thanks for the notes about the **"Network Error" without any response** issue. I got the same problem and your explanation helped!

Comment: Where do you put this code?

Answer (score 10):

We can catch axios 401 using this method.

```
 axios.post('/add')
 .then(function (response) {...})
 .catch(function (error) {
     console.log(error.response.status) // 401
     console.log(error.response.data.error) //Please Authenticate or whatever returned from server
   if(error.response.status==401){
     //redirect to login
   }
 })
```

Comment: When I get 401, there is no response in error! also it doesn't go into catch block

Comment: The problem is we do not add error catching to every api call and better way of doing would be manipulating response with interceptors

Answer (score 5):

I consulted some other questions and here is my code

```
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ? 'http://localhost:5001/api/v1' : 'https://api.mysite.com/api/v1'
});
instance.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';

//validate response
instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return response;
}, (error) => {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {

            return window.location.href = '/login'
        }
    return Promise.reject(error);
});

// Set the AUTH token for any request
instance.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        config.headers.Authorization =  token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '';
        return config;
    }
)

export default instance;
```

Comment: It is just to redirect the login page rather than updating the token and letting user use the service.

Comment: yes. It is my bussiness logic ! You can custom it base on your requirements !

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a clear concise answer when using Axios in a module. You need to add the interceptors to the *instance* of axios you are using.

**api.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '../state'

//Defaults will be combined with the instance
axios.defaults.baseURL = '/some/page.aspx';

//Create Axios Instance
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    }
});

//Add interceptors to instance
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    error => {
        if (!error.response) {
            store.commit('setServiceAvailable', false);
        }
        else if (error.response.status === 401) {
            store.commit('setUserAuthorised', false);
        }
        return error;
    });

export default axiosInstance;
```

Then use as normal

**component.js**

```
import api from '../api'
...
async getServersJson() {
    try {
        var response = await api.post('GetReportAsServers', {name: 'get-servers', args: null});
        this.serversJson = this.prettifyJson(response.data.d);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(`Exception getting servers. ${error}`);
    }
},
```