# How to detect a 401 with axios and stop the console error

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to use axios to call an API and return data.

I have the following code which works fine

```
axios.get('http://api/courses')
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.status);
    } else {
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
  });
```

This works fine, the API returns a 200 and data so in the console I get the data returned.

However this does not work

```
axios.get('http://api/courses')
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.status);
    } else {
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
  });
```

On the above call i get a 401 returned from the API, I want to be able to detect that and do something (where i am currently doing a console.log). However in the console I get the following errors:

```
GET http://api/courses 401 (Unauthorized)
(anonymous) @ spread.js:25
e.exports @ spread.js:25
e.exports @ spread.js:25
Promise.then (async)
r.request @ spread.js:25
r.(anonymous function) @ spread.js:25
(anonymous) @ index.js:20
(anonymous) @ (index):49


(index):58 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
at axios.get.catch.then.response ((index):58)
at <anonymous>
```

Is there a way to capture a 401? It seems like common practice by API's that require auth, but I cannot seem to work it out.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle 401 (Authentication Error) in axios and react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47216452/how-to-handle-401-authentication-error-in-axios-and-react)

Answer (score 36):

You can add an interceptor that will catch all 401 responses. That way you can fire a redirect or any sort of actions you might need. In this example I am dispatching a redux action that will clean up some user data and render the login form.

```js
const UNAUTHORIZED = 401;
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  error => {
    const {status} = error.response;
    if (status === UNAUTHORIZED) {
      dispatch(userSignOut());
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
 }
);
```

Comment: When a request gets a `401` response, setting an interceptor on the Axios instance works, but the `error.response` remains undefined. This happens with Axios 0.18 and 0.19. So this method doesn't work.

Comment: When a failed request with a `401` status code happens and CORS isn't enabled for that authorization pre-flight request, Axios will not get access to the actual response. This needs to be fixed on the server. The advice presented here for Spring Boot is analogous to any other API: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cors-preflight

Comment: did you just throw `dispatch` right in middle of the interceptor and expected that it will work?!!!! jc

Comment: You are missing the point here. This is just a snippet of code. The dispatch function is available in the context that is left out from the answer for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

For me (with axios 0.19) both work:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => response, error => {
    if(error.response.status === 401) store.dispatch(logout);
    return error;
});
```

and

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    if(response.status === 401) store.dispatch(logout);
    return response;
});
```

I'm adding this because I've saw both versions in different sources and also Neil [told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743474/how-to-detect-a-401-with-axios-and-stop-the-console-error#comment99645599_48743630) that the version that uses the error handler to intercept didn't work for them, so may be another one is helpful to somebody too.

Comment: Hi @YakovL, I've updated axios lib with version 0.19.1 but im still getting response: undefined in the interceptor, i need to catch status code 401, is there any solution for it. Please let me konw.

Comment: @Shree would you mind creating a new question and providing the relevant bits of your code there?

Comment: That worked perfectly fine! Thank you very much, but I would like to now more about that. Is the error object in the arrow function the intercepted error coming from javascript?

Comment: @Taranis that's not likely (I guess, that's an enriched object), but it's not that simple to find the exact defintion in the source code (you can try yourself, though); I'd see what is really passed using just console and also read the [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors).

Answer (score 1):

Added debugger to check the object, so this is how the error object looks like.

Refer screenshot. Right side(under scope)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It very easy to catch and handle 401 through the error.response.

```
error => {
    if (err.response.status) {
            props.navigation.navigate('Login');
            return;
         }
         });
```