# Problem with JWT Refresh Token Flow with axios/axios-auth-refresh

Tags: javascript, axios, jwt

(I've read a number of similar questions here, and most/all have said to use a different axios instance for the refresh token requests (versus the API requests). However, I'm not clear on how that would work, since I am using [axios-auth-refresh](https://github.com/Flyrell/axios-auth-refresh) for auto-refreshing the access tokens.)

I'm working on an app with a JWT-based authentication flow for back-end API requests. The general flow is working fine; upon login the user gets a long-term refresh token and short-term access token. Using the [axios-auth-refresh](https://github.com/Flyrell/axios-auth-refresh) plug-in for axios, I am able to auto-refresh the access token when it has expired.

My problem is, when the refresh token expires, I am not able to catch the error and redirect the user to re-authenticate. Nothing I've tried catches the error. The (current) code for the auto-refresh hook is:

```
const refreshAuth = (failed) =>
  axios({ method: "post", url: "token", skipAuthRefresh: true })
    .then(({ status, data: { success, accessToken } }) => {
      console.warn(`status=${status}`);
      if (!success) Promise.reject(failed);

      processToken(accessToken);
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
      failed.response.config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
      return Promise.resolve();
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error("%o", error));
createAuthRefreshInterceptor(axios, refreshAuth);
```

In cases of the refresh token being stale or missing, I see neither the `status=xxx` console line nor the dump of an error object in the `catch()` block.

The actual file this is in is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/rjray/ismdb/blob/50fc5010aea79302f880946d8765956e4b2754b2/frontend/src/utils/queries.js), though it is slightly different than the working version above. Mainly, in the GH version the hook calls `axios.post("token").then(...)` where above I'm making a more explicit call to add the `skipAuthRefresh` parameter. Adding that got me more detailed error traces in the console, but I am still not catching the 401 response via the `catch()`.

I've tried everything I can think of... anything jump out as something I'm missing?

Randy

*(Edited to ensure the GitHub link points to the version of the file that has the issue.)*

Answer (score 3):

Since posting this, I have managed to work through the problem and come up with a working solution.

The key to the solution **does in fact** lie in using a different axios instance for the calls to renew the refresh token. I created a second module to encapsulate a second axios instance that would not get the interceptor created by the `axios-auth-refresh` module. After working around some inadvertent circular-dependency issues that this initially caused, I reached a point where I could see the exception being thrown by axios when the refresh token itself is stale or missing.

(Interestingly, this led to another problem: once I recognized that the refresh token was no longer valid, I needed to log the user out and have them return to the login screen. Because the application this is in is a React application, the authentication was being handled with custom hooks, which can only be called within a component. However, I had abstracted all the API calls into a non-React module so that I could encapsulate things like the addition of the `Authorization` header, the base URL, etc. At that level I could not run the auth hook to get access to the logout logic. I solved this by putting a default `onError` handler on the query object (a [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) object) that I use for all the API calls.)

Answer (score 1):

I built upon the `Request` class from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47218004/2076073) to refresh the token and handle the refresh failures.

Now my `Request` looks like this:

```js
import axios from "axios";

import {getLocalStorageToken, logOut, refreshToken} from "./authentication";

class Request {

  ADD_AUTH_CONFIG_HEADER = 'addAuth'

  constructor() {
    this.baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_USER_ROUTE;
    this.isRefreshing = false;
    this.failedRequests = [];
    this.axios = axios.create({
      baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_USER_ROUTE,
      headers: {
        clientSecret: this.clientSecret,
      },
    });
    this.beforeRequest = this.beforeRequest.bind(this);
    this.onRequestFailure = this.onRequestFailure.bind(this);
    this.processQueue = this.processQueue.bind(this);
    this.axios.interceptors.request.use(this.beforeRequest);//<- Intercepting request to add token
    this.axios.interceptors.response.use(this.onRequestSuccess,
      this.onRequestFailure);// <- Intercepting 401 failures
  }

  beforeRequest(request) {
    if (request.headers[this.ADD_AUTH_CONFIG_HEADER] === true) {
      delete request.headers[this.ADD_AUTH_CONFIG_HEADER];
      const token = getLocalStorageToken();//<- replace getLocalStorageToken with your own way to retrieve your current token
      request.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    return request;
  }

  onRequestSuccess(response) {
    return response.data;
  }

  async onRequestFailure(err) {
    console.error('Request failed', err)
    const {response} = err;
    const originalRequest = err.config;

    if (response.status === 401 && err && originalRequest && !originalRequest.__isRetryRequest) {
      if (this.isRefreshing) {
        try {
          const token = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {//<- Queuing new request while token is refreshing and waiting until they get resolved
            this.failedRequests.push({resolve, reject});
          });
          originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
          return this.axios(originalRequest);
        } catch (e) {
          return e;
        }
      }
      this.isRefreshing = true;
      originalRequest.__isRetryRequest = true;
      console.log('Retrying request')
      console.log('Previous token', getLocalStorageToken())
      try {
        const newToken = await refreshToken()//<- replace refreshToken with your own method to get a new token (async)
        console.log('New token', newToken)
        originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${newToken}`;
        this.isRefreshing = false;
        this.processQueue(null, newToken);
        return this.axios(originalRequest)
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error refreshing the token, logging out', err);
        await logOut();//<- your logout function (clean token)
        this.processQueue(err, null);
        throw response;//<- return the response to check on component layer whether response.status === 401 and push history to log in screen
      }
    }
    throw response;
  }

  processQueue(error, token = null) {
    this.failedRequests.forEach((prom) => {
      if (error) {
        prom.reject(error);
      } else {
        prom.resolve(token);
      }
    });
    this.failedRequests = [];
  }
}

const request = new Request();

export default request;
```

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is, when the refresh token expires, I am not able to catch
> the error and redirect the user to re-authenticate. Nothing I've tried
> catches the error. The (current) code for the auto-refresh hook is:

What is the return code from your api if the access token expired ?

if it is different than 401 (default) you need to configure, see exanoke 403:

```
createAuthRefreshInterceptor(axios, refreshAuthLogic, {
  statusCodes: [ 401, 403 ] // default: [ 401 ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this wasn't the issue here (my backend is only returning 401's on authorization errors). I need to answer my own question, as I've since figured out the solution.