# JWT auth process - frontend part

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, jwt

Im making a user authorization process with JWT tokens.

How does the flow look like?

1. User logs in - gets an access token and a refresh token from a server, as a response
2. Access token comes in json body and is saved in local storage. Refresh token comes in a httpOnly cookie.
3. User can use `getAllUsers` method untill access token is valid.
4. Whenever `getAllUsers` method returns `401 unauthorized` (when access token expires), there is a request being sent to refresh token endpoint - `getRefreshToken`, which returns new access token  that is being saved to local storage
5. Refresh token expires and user is being logged out.

**Whole flow in Postman works but i have got problem at frontend side.**

**Function `getAllUsers` works until access token expires.**

Thats why I made a global function in a util file that checks if a response is `401` and if so, it sends a request to get a new access token and calls a function which returned that error.
**However it does not work.**

I think that the problem is in `getAllUsers` function which immediately goes to `catch` block (when cant fetch list of users because of `401`) and does not invoke that global function from util file. Console logs from both functions (`getDataFromResponse`, `getRefreshToken`) does not work so it does not even get there.

Any ideas??

**API utils file**

```
import { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { apiService } from "./api.service";

type ApiServiceMethods = keyof typeof apiService;

export const getDataFromResponse = async (
  response: AxiosResponse,
  funName: ApiServiceMethods,
  ...args: any
): Promise<any> => {
  if (response.status === 401) {
    console.log("error");
    await apiService.getRefreshToken();
    return await apiService[funName](args);
  }

  return response.data;
};
```

**API Service:**

```
import { getDataFromResponse } from "./api.utils";
import axios from "./axios";

type LoginArgs = {
  password: string;
  username: string;
};

const apiServiceDef = () => {
  const login = async (args: LoginArgs) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/login", {
        username: args.username,
        password: args.password,
      });

      const { data } = response;
      const { token } = data;

      localStorage.setItem("accessToken", token);

      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error("Custom");
    }
  };

/* problem here */
  const getAllUsers = async () => {
    const Token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

    try {
      const response = await axios.get("/users", {
        headers: {
          Token,
        },
      });
      return await getDataFromResponse(response, "getAllUsers");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
/* problem here */

  const getRefreshToken = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("fetch new access token");

      const response = await axios.get("/refreshToken");

      
      if (response.status === 401) {
        localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
        throw new Error("TokenExpiredError");
      }

      const { data } = response;
      const { token } = data

      localStorage.setItem("accessToken", token);

      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  return { login, getRefreshToken, getAllUsers };
};

export const apiService = apiServiceDef();
```

Comment: I dont understand all the upvotes then, what exacly is your problem? What I read is that you cannot call the `getAllUsers` method because  it returns 401. But then you say it works?! (in my awnser I deleted)

Comment: You dont send the access token to the server, the one you want to refresh. Usually the refreshToken call needs the current access token the user is using. So you need to pass the `Authorization: 'Bearer {token}'` also to the refresh token call.

Comment: Nope, my middleware on the backend side requires only refresh token that is being sent back as a cookie with each request. Then it checks if its still valid and has no expired. If it didnt it sends new access token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use a wrapper around the async functions or just use axios interceptors (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47216863/11787903). Be sure that `err.response.status` is right property, not sure about that, but this solution should work for you.

```
const asyncWrapper = async (handler) => {
  try {
    return handler()
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response.status === 401) {
      // refresh token then again call handler
      await refreshToken()
      return handler()
    }
  }
}
const getAllUsers = asyncWrapper(() => {
  const Token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

  return axios.get("/users", {
    headers: {
      Token,
    },
  });
});
```